# How to add a column by matching with previous year?

Tags: r

I have a data frame as following:

```
df1

ID   closingdate   
 1   31/12/2005   
 2   01/12/2009   
 3   02/01/2002   
 4   09/10/2000   
 5   15/11/2007
```

I want to add a third column (let's call it infoyear) in my df that shows the year before for each data element that I have in my second column.
In other words I want to get the following result:

```
df1

ID    closingdate   infoyear
 1    31/12/2005     2004
 2    01/12/2009     2008
 3    02/01/2002     2001
 4    09/10/2000     1999
 5    15/11/2007     2006
```

Normally, to add a column presenting only years I would use:

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df1)[, infoyear := year(as.IDate(closingdate, '%d/%m/%Y'))]
```

In my case it would produce me the following:

```
df1

ID    closingdate   infoyear
 1    31/12/2005     2005
 2    01/12/2009     2009
 3    02/01/2002     2002
 4    09/10/2000     2000
 5    15/11/2007     2007
```

But instead of this result for column infoyear, I would like 1 year before closingdate (as the result presented before).

How can I solve a problem like this in R? Thank you!

Comment: Why not `setDT(df1)[, infoyear := year(as.IDate(closingdate, '%d/%m/%Y'))-1]`

Comment: ohh.. so simple and it works great! I was overcomplicating it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ID   closingdate   
1   31/12/2005   
2   01/12/2009   
3   02/01/2002   
4   09/10/2000
5   15/11/2007")

setDT(df1)
df1[, closingdate:= as.IDate(closingdate,"%d/%m/%Y")]
df1[, infoyear:= year(closingdate)-1]
df1

#Output
   ID closingdate infoyear
1:  1  2005-12-31     2004
2:  2  2009-12-01     2008
3:  3  2002-01-02     2001
4:  4  2000-10-09     1999
5:  5  2007-11-15     2006
```

Comment: perfect solution! Thank you very much :)